# .Net Page.IsValid always returns false when value is set by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In My .Net Page i use validation on Textboxes .In some of this Text Boxes i set value by javascript. But when I click on the submit button ,then it passes to the browser safely but at server side Page.IsValid is false and when reponse is come again at browser then the validators error message start display.I dont know what is wrong here.

**For setting TextBox value**

```
$("input[id*='txtPPIAPrice']").val('0');
$("input[id*='txtPPICPrice']").val('0') ;
$("input[id*='txtPPFAPrice']").val('0');
$("input[id*='txtPPFCPrice']").val('0');
```

**At ServerSide use this check**

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    //My code
}
```

Comment: May you plz but your javascript code and your page.isvalid code..

Comment: are you using Requiredfieldvalidators in webpage.

Comment: yes both Required and RegularExpression, but only RequiredFieldValidators error message shown

Answer (score 1):

> If you have Required field validators in webpage, you need to set validataiongroup    attribute to the each RequiredValidator.

And then your code will look like this

```
Page.Validate("validategroupname");
if(Page.IsValid == true){
 // Put your code here
}
```

i hope it will help for you.

Comment: yes,I think problem is that,the value set by javascript in textbox not reflect at server side

Comment: if your textbox has the value then by document.getElementById method you have to get that value from textbox and pass it to your function that you have called at server side.

Comment: hey got the solution,actually i am disabled the textbox by the javascript.And because of this reason it fails the server validation.I change the disabled to readonly and it works correctly now,Thanks for your support

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26505/discussion-between-rahul-and-vishwajeet-singh-chouhan)